# Javascript string regex /.*/gm does not catch all line at once

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Why does javascript replace string function do this?

```js
"aaa\nbbb\nccc".replace(/.*/gm, ".")
// result = "..\n..\n.." but expected was: ".\n.\n."

"aaa\nbbb\nccc".replace(/^.*/gm, ".")
// result = ".\n.\n." -> OK!!!

"aaa\nbbb\nccc".replace(/.*$/gm, ".")
// result = "..\n..\n.." but expected was: ".\n.\n."
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me address those in reverse order:

> What I am doing wrong?

You want to use `+`, not `*`. `*` means *zero or more* matches, which makes no sense here. `+` means *one or more* matches. So:

```
"aaa\nbbb\nccc".replace(/.+/g, ".")
// ".\n.\n."
```

Also note that if you're not using `^` or `$` (your first example), you don't need the `m` modifier (but that wasn't the problem with what you were doing). And you don't need `^` or `$` because `.` [doesn't match newlines](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2012/03/match-everythingexcept.html) (something I didn't know prior to answering this question).

> Why does javascript replace string function do this?

<s>I have no Earthly idea and hope someone else does.</s>

Again, by using `*` you're saying *zero or more* matches. So it matches all of the relevant characters, replacing them with the first dot; then it matches *zero* characters, replacing them with one dot. Result: Two dots.

Proof:

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/iweyak) | [Live source](http://jsbin.com/iweyak/edit)

```
"aaa\nbbb\nccc".replace(/.*/g, function(m) {
    console.log("m = '" + m + "'");
});
```

Outputs:

```
m = 'aaa'
m = ''
m = 'bbb'
m = ''
m = 'ccc'
m = ''
```

Comment: I love the "Live source". Great explanation.

Comment: Great explanation, this deserves +a_lot. Didn't know that `.` didn't match newlines as well.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this instruction:

```
"aaa\nbbb\nccc".replace(/(.*)/gm, ".$1.")
```

produces:

```
".aaa...
.bbb...
.ccc..."
```

`.*` matches `aaa` and replaces it by `.aaa.`, then it matches an empty string and replacess by `..`.

The same behaviour when you replace `.*` by `.`

As said T.J. Crowder, use this one instead : `.+`

```
"aaa\nbbb\nccc".replace(/.+/g, ".")
```

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, the behavior is expected. An empty string satisfies the regular expression `.*`:

```
/.*/.test("");
// true

/.*/.exec("");
// [""]
```

To understand what's going on, notice the output of:

```
"aaa\nbbb\nccc".match(/.*/g);
// ["aaa", "", "bbb", "", "ccc", ""]
// m flag dropped because ^ and $ are not used
```

Keeping in mind that `.` does not match `\n`, the match-replacement is done as follows:

- `.*` matches `aaa`
- because of `g` flag, the string after `aaa` is searched for a match

  - `.*` matches `""` -- a zero length string after `aaa` and before `\n`
  - `.*` does not match `\n`
  - `.*` matches `bbb`
  - `.*` matches `""` -- a zero length string after `bbb` and before `\n`

And so on. Just use `.+` to avoid matching empty strings.

Comment: ".* does not match \n". Good to know.